# Nhibernate not returning right result sometime

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate

So here is my nhibernate query.
I am just querying in database if there is latest entry by some number but with latest time stamp.

So like if I have

```
Row A   6     1/7/2010 2:55:59 PM
Row B   6     1/7/2010 2:56:33 PM
```

So According to the query it should return Row B but sometimes it is not happening.
Can anyone point out the problem in my hibernate query.

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(x));
        subquery.SetProjection(Projections.Max("Time"));


        X x = (X)_mapper.Run(delegate(ISession session, object[] arguments)
        {
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(X));
            criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("ID", ID));
            criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Time", subquery));
            return criteria.UniqueResult();
        }, true);

        return x;
```

Comment: Have you looked at and can you post the SQL statement that is generated for this query?

Comment: Do you know how to generate SQL query out of it, Because I don't

Comment: NHibernate logs all the SQL to log4net; See blog post: http://www.davesquared.net/2008/01/viewing-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html.  Alternatively, if you have the rights you can just use SQL Profiler.

Comment: In this query, what is ID? Also, you should try voting once in a while!

Comment: That is some number by which I narrow down my search.In the above example it is 6. And I do vote If I get the correct answer.

Comment: so i guess you've yet to receive a good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery isn't filtered down by ID like the actual query - if the maximum time regardless of ID happens to be on a row with the ID in question, you'll get the row you want; if it doesn't, you won't. You need to add a filter where you create the subquery:

```
.Add( Expression.Eq("ID", ID) )
```

Comment: Actually I found out that already.When I saw your response It just confirmed.